# shared_ptr from pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, shared-ptr

I have a class which can't be created on heap and it has private destructor.

But there is a function which returns a pointer to such constructed object. I want to make a shared pointer from it:

```
MyClass *GetMyClassPointer() {...}

boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr;
ptr = boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>(GetMyClassPointer()); // [x]
```

> error: ‘MyClass::~MyClass()’ is
>   private

Any ways?

Comment: You should provide more information on what the semantics of the class are. The class might be implementing a singleton, in which case the answer is that you should not use a `shared_ptr` at all, or the class might be implementing a factory or a memory pool in which you have to release the objects back to the same factory... the answers depend on the information that you are not showing in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

It sounds like the instance is being dynamically allocated by a function which has access to the private constructor (either member or friend).  Then there should be a public function for cleaning up the instance when you're done with it, which has access to the private destructor (even though you don't).

Use the `shared_ptr` constructor that accepts a custom deleter, and wire it up to the cleanup function the class provides (may need a wrapper function to get the signature to match).

Comment: Custom deleter is indeed the way to go here.